# Not able to Extract JSON response for Post call with Rest assured

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest

Can someone help me in extracting the JSON response? I want to fetch the value for asset and ID and name under client and assert it in my code. Nothing is working for me to extract these values in my java code

```
[
    {
        "metadata": {
            "asset": "ef59872625",
            "customerInfo": {
                "client": {
                    "id": "0CgIHVIA3",
                    "name": "JAssociates"
                }
            },
            "adInfo": {
                "title": "Te1",
                "adId": "Te1",
                "cartNumber": "98462",
                "dueDate": "2021-06-23",
                "dubber": {
                    "id": null,
                    "name": null,
                    "email": null
                },
                "archiveOn": "2021-06-29",
                "eraseOn": "2021-09-24",
                "length": {
                    "unit": "seconds",
                    "amount": 30
                },
                "creatID": 15813794
            },
            "targetInfo": [
                {
                    "channelType": "AA",
                    "market": {
                        "id": 400,
                        "name": "Dallas, TX",
                        "Status": "Success",
                        "Status2": {
                            "state": "Submitted",
                            "message": null
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "https://interntadata",
                "type": "metadata"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://interntent",
                "type": "content"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Any pointers It would be a great help

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Please explain clearly and post relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

**1) First, get the response body by hitting the URL.**

```
Response resp =  RestAssured.given().headers("Content-Type", ContentType.JSON, "Accept", ContentType.JSON).
                when().get("{{YOUR-URL}}").
                then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response();
        String responseBody = resp.getBody().asString();
```

**2) Extract Value from JSON:**

**First Method: Using JsonPath**

```
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
```

---

```
JsonPath js = new JsonPath(responseBody);
String asset = js.getString("metadata.asset");
System.out.println(asset);
String id = js.getString("metadata.customerInfo.client.id");
System.out.println(id);
String name = js.getString("metadata.customerInfo.client.name");
System.out.println(name);
```

**Second Method:**

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

---

```
JSONArray object = new JSONArray(responseBody);
JSONObject metadataObj = ((JSONObject)object.get(0)).getJSONObject("metadata");
String asset = metadataObj.getString("asset");
System.out.println(asset);
JSONObject customerInfoObject = metadataObj.getJSONObject("customerInfo");
JSONObject clientObject = customerInfoObject.getJSONObject("client");
String id = clientObject.getString("id");
System.out.println(id);
String name = clientObject.getString("name");
System.out.println(name);
```

---

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
```